# Bash 4.4 vi-mode coloring

Tags: bash, bash4

since bash 4.4 you can set variables vi-ins-mode-string and vi-cmd-string in .inputrc. I've been trying to change the foreground and background color of each of those strings by using `tput setab number` and `tput setaf number`, no success.

I guess it is possible as I've seen bash-powerline script and it uses exactly those functions to do the coloring.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not `bash` variables, but `readline` variables, so they can only be set in `.inputrc`, which is not a `bash` script. You need to use the raw ASCII escape sequences.

```
set editing-mode vi
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[32m\2(c)\1\e[0m\2
set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[34m\2(i)\1\e[0m\2
```